# How to schedule a task on Hazelcast that queries on the IMap?

Tags: serialization, scheduled-tasks, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I want to schedule a task on Hazelcast that runs at a fixed interval and updates the IMap with some data that I get after hitting a rest endpoint. Below is a sample code:

// Main class

```
IScheduledExecutorService service = hazelcast.getScheduledExecutorService("default");

service.scheduleAtFixedRate(TaskUtils.named("my-task", myTask), 30, 1);
```

// Task

```
@Singleton
public class MyTask implements Runnable, Serializable {

    RestClient restClient;

    IMap<String, JsonObject> map;

    @Inject
    MyTask() { // Inject hazelcast and restclient
        map = hazelcastInstace.getMap("my-map");
        this.restClient = restClient;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Collection<JSONObject> values = map.values(new MyCustomFilter());
        for(JSONObject obj : values) {
             // query endpoint based on id
             map.submitToKey(key, response);
        }

    }


    private static class MyCustomFilter implements Predicate<String, JSONObject> {

        public boolean apply(Map.Entry<String, JSONObject> map) {
             // logic to filter relevant keys
        }

    }
}
```

When I try to execute this on the cluster, I get:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl
```

Now I need the IMap to selectively query only some keys based on PredicateFilter and this needs to be a background scheduled job so stuck here on how to take this forward. Any help appreciated. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making your task also implement [HazelcastInstanceAware](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/4.0.3/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/HazelcastInstanceAware.html)

When you submit your task, it is serialized, sent to the grid to run, deserialized when it is received, and the `run()` method is called.

If your task implements `HazelcastInstanceAware`, then between deserialization and `run()`, Hazelcast will call the method `setHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstance instance)` to pass your code a reference to the particular Hazelcast instance it is running in. From there you can just do `instance.getMap("my-map")` and store the map reference in a transient field that the `run()` method can use.

Comment: I see. So looks like I am injecting the `HazelcastInstance` too early. So even if I have class level property for `HazelcastInstance` instead of `IMap`, wont it still be serialized to send to the executing node?(or that will be null at the time of serialization so its fine?) Haven't tried the above yet, just curious.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for this. Works fine. Although now, running into errors now that RestClient needs to be serializable but that is a separate issue.